# Unable to update guest OS hard drive size

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive, vmware-fusion

I am running VMWare Fusion 6.0.4 on OS X 10.10.3.  I have Windows 7 as the guest OS.  Originally I had the hard drive set to 60GB. It was running out of space so I increased it to 100GB.  However, Windows 7 still thinks there is only 60GB on the C: drive.  Fusion thinks there is 100, on the Windows side, in disk management, Disk0 is listed as 100GB, but the C: volume is 60GB and the option to extend it is greyed out.  How do I get my 40GB to be recognized?

Comment: So you expanded it using VMWare right?  Does the disk partition tool see the unallocated space?

Comment: Yes, I adjusted it with VMware. In the Disk Management tool, the bottom section listing the physical disks lists Disk0 as 100GB. But, the list of volumes lists C: as having a capacity of 60GB.  The extend option is unavailable.

Comment: At this point, I have created a new vm, an have the old one archived.  I am still interested if there is a non-destructive way to reallocate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of useful information in this VMWare Knowledge Base Article:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004071

Comment: I checked that out and went through all of the non-destructive tasks without success.